# How to divide Json strings.?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have 4 models **Category**, **Vendor**, **Location**, **Product**. **Vendor** fall under the **Category** model (vendor is a foreign key to category). The remaining models are under **Vendor** (**Location**, **Product**)

**ProductSerializer** and **LocationSerializer** are nested to **VendorSerializer**, and **VendorSerializer** is nested to **CategorySerializer**.

```
class ProductSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'item_name', 'price']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

class LocationSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['place']

class VendorSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    vendor_location = LocationSerializer()
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = ['vendor_name','vendor_location','product']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

class CategorySerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    vendor = VendorSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'category_name', 'tittle', 'vendor']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

**# View**

```
class ProductView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        products = Category.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorySerializer(products, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response({'response': 'ok', 'result': serializer.data})
```

**# Output**

```
{
    "response": "ok",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name": "Cake",
            "tittle": "test title",
            "vendor": [                
                {
                    "vendor_name": "Test_Name",
                    "vendor_location": {
                        "place": "Test_Place"
                    },
                    "product": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "item_name": "test_1",
                            "price": 3200,
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "item_name": "test_2",
                            "price": 2010,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**# Expected output**

```
{
    "response": "ok",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name": "Cake",
            "tittle": "test title",
            "vendor": [                
                {
                    "vendor_name": "Test_Name",
                    "vendor_location": {
                        "place": "Test_Place"
                    },
                    "product": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "item_name": "test_1",
                            "price": 3200,
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name": "Cake",
            "tittle": "test title",
            "vendor": [                
                {
                    "vendor_name": "Test_Name",
                    "vendor_location": {
                        "place": "Test_Place"
                    },
                    "product": [                  
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "item_name": "test_2",
                            "price": 2010,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my output, two products are listed. There may be more than two. I only need one product under the product. All products must be printed in the same structure as I mentioned in expected output. How do I do this? Is it possible? Can someone help me do this?

Comment: what's difference in the format? it seems like same

Comment: @amankumar : in my output, there are two products listed.it may have more than two. I need only one product in the product section.  and I need to print all products with the same structure

Comment: from database point of view it doesn't make any sense, multiple product has relation to that 1 category , it's correct to list all of them in the same category, and query shouldn't return the same value multiple times

Comment: @LinhNguyen : OK. Is there any way to divide this structure as I mentioned above? Is it possible to divide it like this?

Comment: That product = ProductSerializer(many=True) declaration in your VendorSerializer class... is it really a one to many relationship?

Comment: @JDE10 : I don't know how to really get into this structure. So my first priority is to print all the data. The product is a many to one relationship with the Vendor (the product connects to the vendor with ForeignKey)

Comment: But that way you will get many products inside the same vendor node, not a separate item for each kit of name, location, product

Comment: @JDE10 : Yes I know. I ask you how to divide it. Which part do I need to change? How can I get to this expected output

Comment: @Mike_Wazowski I'd try to use ProductSerializer() instead of ProductSerializer(many=True) and see what happens. Sorry I can't give you anything but a clue.

Comment: @JDE10 : It doesn't work. I already tried that before posting this question

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this line:

```py
# old:
products = Category.objects.all()  # definately these are not products
# new:
products = Product.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)  # get all products ids
categories = Category.objects.filter(vendor__product__in=products)
```

And send `categories` to `CategorySerializer`, thought this is still not what you want, as every duplicated category will hold information about all products (not only one).
Where I would go from this point? I'd create method `get_product` in `VendorSerializer` and somehow save information what `Category`/`Vendor` are we in right now and if we have already added a `Product` for this `Category` - I'd skip adding next.

PS. I still don't get why you need this format though.

Comment: According to UI, the developer told me to build a structure like this. I don't know if it's actually possible. That is why I posted this question. I can give you the UI design, and can you suggest a better Jason format for that UI.?

Comment: Please do, maybe will come up with better JSON format.

Comment: If these are 4 products from one category, then the response you provide is fully valid and proper. You don't want to send so many duplicated information. Frontend developer can easily map this response to models and iterate products in it.

Comment: Name and title of the top section according to UI. This is from the category model.

Product has product image, item name shop name, location and price.

The shop name and location is from the vendor model.

The item name and price will come from the product model.

There are many vendors, and each one of them has multiple products.

Comment: Which do you suggest for this UI. output or expected output.?

Comment: Definitely `output`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203024/discussion-between-mike-wazowski-and-marek).